# Is it possible to get instance of driver inside HtmlBlock in HtmlElements?

Tags: selenium, htmlelements

I'm using the `HtmlElements` (https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements) framework for my Java webtests. Is it possible to get an instance of webdriver inside `HtmlBlock`?
For example, implement extra logic in some fields or implement a function to wait for `ajax` complete.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this code snippet:

```java
@Name("Search form")
@FindBy(xpath = "//form[@class='f1']")
public class SearchArrow extends Test1 {
    public WebDriver driver;
}

public class SearchPage {
    @FindBy(xpath = "//form[@class='f1']")
        private SearchArrow searchArrow;

    public SearchPage(WebDriver driver) {
        HtmlElementLoader.populatePageObject(this, driver);
        searchArrow.driver = driver;
    }
}
```

Originally: https://gist.github.com/artkoshelev/4751a4f1b34211e43f4e

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you. You need WebDriver in you page block class, not in Page class.

Simple way, but not elegant, is create a static variable and save WebDriver instance in it, to get the ability use WebDriver in any placein your code.

Addition I guess you instance Pages in your test and in page constructor you call

```
    HtmlElementLoader.populatePageObject(this, driver);
```

But I think you may try to init your block manualy.

```
class Page {
    @FindBy(...)
    HtmlBlock block;

   public Page(){
       HtmlElementLoader.populatePageObject(this, driver);
       this.block = new HtmlBlock(driver);
   }
}
```

And in HtmlBlock create constructor that save WebDriver to local field.

```
public HtmlBlock(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
    HtmlElementLoader.populatePageObject(this, driver);
}
```

I am not sure in second variant, but something like this should work.